# Can ng-change call another controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following html

```
<div ng-controller="select">        
    <select ng-options="n for n in names" 
    ng-model="selected.item"
    ng-change="change()">
    </select>
</div>
<div ng-controller="graph">
    <input type="text" ng-model="mySelected.item">
    <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-labels="gs" chart-data="ser">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

I want the change() method in ng-option to call the "graph" controller. Basically if the option is changed the graph should be updated. Is there a way to do it. Please help.

I am also sharing my controller code if required:`

```
app.controller('graph', ['$scope', '$http', 'myService', function($scope,$http, myService) {
$scope.mySelected = myService.selected;
console.log($scope.mySelected);
//$http.get('/myapp/stocklist/'+ $scope.mySelected).
$http.get('/myapp/stocklist/AMZN').
success(function(data) {
gs = [];
ser = [];    
for( var i=0; i<data.length; i++ ) {
    gs.push(data[i].name);
    ser.push(data[i].high);
}
$scope.gs=gs;    
$scope.ser=[];
$scope.ser.push(ser);
});
}]);

app.controller('select', ['$scope', '$http', 'myService', function($scope,$http, myService) {
$scope.selected = myService.selected;
$http.get('/myapp/stocknames').
success(function(data) {
    $scope.names=data;
    console.log($scope.names);          
});
}]);
```

Comment: Use events: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit

Comment: You can but to avoid confusion you should publish the controller instance into a property on scope using "controller as".  Read about it here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

Answer (score 0):

In your graph controller you would use $on:

```
    scope.$on('onServiceSelected', function (event, selectedService) {
           $scope.mySelected = selectedService;
    });
```

In your other controller you would use $broadcast:

```
  $rootScope.$broadcast('onServiceSelected',$scope.serviceSelection);
```

This should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi, Can we do it using service. Should we do it using service or this is the preferred way?

Comment: There are many different ways of achieving the same result, you have to weigh the benefits of each for your solution. Did you try my code?

Comment: I did not yet. I just want to make sure that I am using the right way of doing it. Maybe I have not structured the controllers properly. I should use parent child ( I read somewhere :-/)? Just wanted to make sure because I am just in the beginning stages of the project right now.